# Metro interface in Android applications

Tags: android, microsoft-metro

I am a beginner in Android programming.

Is there somewhere a good tutorial for the development of modern interfaces in Android applications.

How do metro interface in Android applications?

For example:
[image]

Or how to make the interface as in the Android Market application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

well, to have a multi page layout that you can swipe through, just use the ViewPager layout manager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

for the tile layout a GridLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) might be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no API support to make applications look like the Market application. Or rather; there is no standard style for this. If you want the UI to look like WP7/Win8 Metro style applications or like the Marketplace application you will probably have to make the style yourself.

You do have some recommendations and best practises when making Android UIs on the developers site. That's a good place to start:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html